# How to permit text selection on jQuery List DragSort elements

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, dragsort

I am using the [dragsort](https://dragsort.codeplex.com/) plugin for dragging elements, but when I use the plugin, I can't select the area where I use dragsort for dragging.

I selected the list area to drag my `p` element with `span` which has drag class;

```
var newitem ='<p >'+'<span class="drag">DRAG|</span> '+ userList +'</p>';
$('#list').append(newitem);
```

.

```
$("#list").dragsort({  dragSelector: ".drag",});
```

I looked plugin source and saw that z-index is 999.Took a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Ez2UITB.png).You can also take a look source code from [here](https://dragsort.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#jquery.dragsort.js). I used `z-index:1000;` for my element in my css but it did not work.

What is the solution ?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/)

Comment: try to add `!important` like `z-index:1000 !important;`

Comment: Already tried mate but not working @aldanux

Comment: did you give your element a position: value? z-index won't work without one

Comment: I gave them but not worked @Shniper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not about the `z-index` value of the element.

To permit text selection with this plugin you should remove the `e.preventDefault();` in the source code (`t.preventDefault();` in the minified version) that affects the base behaviour of the text selection on the browser. [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/19/)

Comment: Thank you i know it  but can we make it works without giving position ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. If you can't give a `position` property to your elements maybe you can give it to their fathers? Be aware that `position: relative` normally has a lighter impact on your layout.

Comment: Man i gave them position but could not make it work. Can you edit my Fiddle?

Comment: Can you show me how you added them and also can you explain in further details your desired results.
I understood that you had problems selecting and/or dragging list elements created with `dragsort`, but on your fiddle I am able to drag the elements correctly.

Comment: My problem is not dragging.Drag is working.My problem i cant select text when i use dragsort plugin , problem probably z-index but i cant make it work.

Comment: MATE THAT MADE ME A HEADACHE.I EVEN CHANGED PLUGIN'S Z-INDEX BUT COULD NOT SELECTED TEXT AGAIN.....

Comment: search for a `t.preventDefault();` in the minified version of `dragsort` plugin and remove it. I'll update the answer. [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cwjm5d4k/19/)

Comment: Dude , can i buy you a beer or more than one?Thanks!